# Why would WHERE IN run extremely slow

Tags: mysql, search

I've been using the following query for some time, but as the results database has grown, it has become slow to the point of being un usable. Could anyone suggest an alternative way of doing this?

I've got fulltext indices on c.name and r.scope

```
SELECT * FROM results r 
        INNER JOIN categories c on r.id = c.result_id 
        INNER JOIN tags t on r.id = t.result_id 
        WHERE c.name in ('purchase', 'single_family', 'other')

        AND ( r.scope = 'all' OR r.scope = 'hi' )
        AND published = 1
    GROUP BY r.id
        HAVING COUNT(c.c_id) >= 3
        ORDER BY r.usefulness DESC
        LIMIT 8 OFFSET 0
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: Here's the result of EXPLAIN

```
  id    select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  c   range   nameindex,name  nameindex   767     NULL    10036   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  t   ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    10229   Using where; Using join buffer
1   SIMPLE  r   eq_ref  PRIMARY,scope   PRIMARY     4   rfw.t.result_id     1   Using where
```

Comment: It is recommendable that you use indexes on field `c.name` to make it faster.

Comment: What does the `EXPLAIN` say?

Comment: do you have index on categories.name?

Comment: I don't think your query is slow because of the where clause, but because of the ORDER BY one.
Anyway, show what EXPLAIN has to say about this if you want help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: query to create index

CREATE INDEX name ON categories (name);

---

Use Explain statement, the output of explain will help you to decide which column require index & other useful information.

As specified in [mysql doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html):

> When you precede a SELECT statement with the keyword EXPLAIN, MySQL
>   displays information from the optimizer about the query execution
>   plan. That is, MySQL explains how it would process the statement,
>   including information about how tables are joined and in which order.

Run this:

```
    EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM results r 
    INNER JOIN categories c on r.id = c.result_id 
    INNER JOIN tags t on r.id = t.result_id 
    WHERE c.name in ('purchase', 'single_family', 'other')

    AND ( r.scope = 'all' OR r.scope = 'hi' )
    AND published = 1
GROUP BY r.id
    HAVING COUNT(c.c_id) >= 3
    ORDER BY r.usefulness DESC
    LIMIT 8 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: Can you create index on name column in categories table and run explain & query again. i have added the sample query that will create index.

Comment: create index on result_id column in tags table after that check execution time of query & output of explain

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much, it's super speedy now!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `fulltext` index here; a regular index is what mySQL will want to use for this field.

A fulltext index is intended for use with fulltext searching (ie the `MATCH .. AGAINST` query); it won't be relevant to a simple equals or `IN ()` query.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to make your query faster, you could do 3 things:

- add index on `c.name` (slow query suggests that you're not having any)
- add `count` to `categories` (with index on it), which would contain cached data
  `WHERE c.count >= 3`  will fetch only limited number of results
  `HAVING COUNT() >= 3` has to fetch all results  before returning
- use `WHERE c.id IN (...)`  instead of `WHERE c.name in ('...)` if possible...
  `id` = `identification` = PRIMARY KEY, this is what it was meant to do

Answer (score -1):

1) Select only required for your answer columns.
2) Setup propertly tables indexes.
Also you can get some info using `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: -1 you basically said to him that he should debug it on his own using explain